# oracle sql dev: SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword 00905. 00000 - "missing keyword"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle sql developer.

On executing the following code, I get a vague sounding error.

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
student_id INT NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR2(30),
email VARCHAR2(80),
password VARCHAR2(30),
f_name VARCHAR2(30),
l_name VARCHAR2(30),
bio VARCHAR2(350),
dp VARCHAR2(15),
is_suspended CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
suspension_reason VARCHAR2(50),
role_id INT NOT NULL,
created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
updated_on TIMESTAMP,
is_active CHAR(1) DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
state VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
zip VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
b_day DATE,
CONSTRAINT students_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(student_id),
CONSTRAINT students_role_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(role_id),
CONSTRAINT students_username_uq UNIQUE(username),
CONSTRAINT students_email_uq UNIQUE(email)
);
```

The error is:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

please advice.

Comment: DB2 tags are missing

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a foreign key constraint is:

```
CONSTRAINT students_role_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(role_id) REFERENCES roles(role_id)
----------------------------------------------------^
```

You are missing the `REFERENCES` keyword and the appropriate table/column afterwards (which may not be correct in the above answer).

This is at least one error.

Comment: thats the only error. thanks. are there any syntactical changes i need to make to implement the above code in MariaDb?

Comment: @user3650571 . . . MariaDB -- to a very close approximation -- uses exactly the same syntax as MySQL.  In any case, this is ANSI standard syntax and supported by many databases.